# Left Join throw Hibernate annotation

Tags: hibernate, annotations, left-join

I have annotaion like this:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ACK_BY", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", nullable = true)
public User ackBy;
```

When I want to filter main table by user's name it generate sql query like this:

```
from ALARMS alarm0_ cross join USER user1_ where alarm0_.ACK_BY=user1_.USER_ID and (user1_.key not like 'value' or user1_.key is null)
```

How to say **hibernate** that i want use left join like this:

```
ALARMS alarm0_ left join USER user1_ on alarm0_.ACK_BY=user1_.USER_ID (user1_.key not like 'value' or user1_.key is null)
```

**UPD:** I cant use HQL for resolve this issue.

Comment: Using a left join? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins. What's your current HQL query?

Comment: Then how are you generating the above request? And what's your database?

Answer (score 0):

So looks like its not possible throw annotation. You should use HQL for this situatuion.